# Describe explicitly a minimal free resolution

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, formal-power-series

I have a problem

> Let $R=k[[x,y]]$. Describe explicitly a minimal free resolution of $R$-module $R/(x^2,xy,y^3)$.

I don't have a clue what I should do. Normally I studied the abstract theory and just admit the existence of minimal free resolution. So I am clueless when it comes to a specific situation.

Thank you for your help

Comment: First find a minimal set of generators for your module. That defines a map from a free module. Next find a minimal set of generators for the kernel of this map. That defines the next map from a free module. Etc. etc.

Comment: I know thats how we do it. But explicit presenting is hard. The first free module is R, the second one is R^3. Then i am dead-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R\rightarrow R/(x^2,xy,y^3)$ be the canonical projection. It's kernel is the ideal $(x^2,xy,y^3)$. Consider the map $$R^3\rightarrow (x^2,xy,y^3),\;\; e_1\mapsto x^2, e_2\mapsto xy, e_3\mapsto y^3,$$ where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is the canonical basis of $R^3$. The kernel of this map is generated by $ye_1-xe_2$ and $y^2e_2-xe_3$. The map $$R^2 \rightarrow (ye_1-xe_2,y^2e_2-xe_3)R,\;\; f_1\mapsto ye_1-xe_2, f_2\mapsto y^2e_2-xe_3$$ is an isomorphism, where $\{f_1,f_2\}$ is the canonical basis of $R^2$.

So, the minimal free resolution of $R/(x^2,xy,y^3)$ is 
$$ 0 \rightarrow R^2 \rightarrow R^3 \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/(x^2,xy,y^3) \rightarrow 0.$$
(The matrix of the map $R^2\rightarrow R^3$ has entries in $(x,y,z)R$. Same for the map $R^3\rightarrow R$.)

Comment: It would be nice to show that the first kernel is generated by $ye_1-xe_2$ and $y^2e_2-xe_3$.

Comment: A start to the proof user26857 was asking for: suppose $a (x^2) + b (xy) + c (y^3) = 0$.  Then $a$ must be divisible by $y$, so $a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3 \equiv b' e_2 + c' e_3$ modulo $\langle ye_1 - xe_2, y^2 e_2 - x e_3\rangle$ for some $b', c'$.  Now similarly, $b'$ is divisible by $y^2$, etc.